# Geometric group theory and category theory.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, category-theory, soft-question

Are there any classical results in geometric group theory which leverage categorical techniques or results? I know that category theory has been very useful in fields like algebraic topology and algebraic geometry, but are there any classical results in GGT which can be proved or understood via category theoretic tools?

For example the fact that continuous endomorphisms of $D^2$ must have fixed points (to me) seemed like something one could prove with topological/analytic tools, but functoriality of $\pi_1$ is a slick way to prove the result, I don't even know if proofs that don't leverage this exist.

Thanks in advance.